# Regex: Combination of String Length and Starts With patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I want to check if the string contains exactly 11 characters, not more or less, and also if it starts with the numbers '09', so my pattern is:

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"^(?=09)(?={11})");
Console.WriteLine(rg.IsMatch("09123456789"));
```

`^(?=09)` is working correctly, but when I add second part, `(?={11})`, an exception will be thrown. What's the right pattern?

Comment: Why don't you just use `^09.{9}$`?

Comment: @SebastianProske denn ich habe dass nicht  gewusst ;)
Please post it as the answer and mention what is the char '$' doing so I can mark your answer as the best :)

Comment: `$` marks end of line, like `^` marks start of line.

Comment: Actually, for validation purposes, it is more appropriate to use `\z` instead of `$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Regex(@"^09[0-9]{9}$");
```

pattern for valid string

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve that without a regex:

```
if (s.Length == 11 && s.StartsWith("09") && s.All(Char.IsDigit))
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/IDXN0E) (not sure you need to have digits only. If not, remove `s.All(Char.IsDigit)`).

Note that `^(?=09)(?={11})` matches a start of string position (with `^`), then checks if the string starts with `09` substring, and then requires `{11}` *literal char sequence* at the beginning of a string. That can't work since `09` != `{1`.

If you need a regex  you may use

```
\A09[0-9]{9}\z
```

or, to match not only digits:

```
\A09.{9}\z
```

where

- `\A` - asserts the start of a string
- `09` - matches a literal char sequence `09`
- `.{9}` - matches 9 chars other than LF
- `\z` - the *very* end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Regex rg = new Regex(@"^09.{9}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
bool CheckStringRegex(string str)
{
    return rg.IsMatch(str);
}
```

but I suggest to do in simpler, without regexes

```
bool CheckString(string str)
{
    return str.Length == 11 && str.StartsWith("09");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `^(?=09)\w{11}$` ?

**DEMO [click me](https://regex101.com/r/CZpeBQ/3)**